# How to Attach an event listener to ElementsByClassName()

Tags: javascript, snackjs

I am using the SnackJS API. And I need to attach an event to each input element (Textbox) with the class name of "qty". I am not able to use the id attribute for this, as it is dynamically generated and unique, and is being used by something else:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    snack.ready(function () {
        // Do your work.
        // Attach an event to QTY Textbox elements.
        var listener = snack.listener({
            node: document.getElementsByClassName("qty"),
            event: 'blur'
        }, function () {
            alert("hello, element.");
        });

        listener.detach();
        listener.attach();
    });
</script>
```

How do I use `getElementByClassName`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either loop over the NodeList that `getElementsByClassName` returns (calling `snack.listener` each time you go around the loop), or delegate the event handler as per [the API documentation](http://snackjs.com/#snack.listener):

```
var params = {
  node: document.body,
  event: 'click',
  delegate: function (node){
    return node.getElementsByClassName('qty')
  }
}
snack.listener(params, someFunction);
```

Comment: So this is how I have it now: http://jsfiddle.net/ZN48Q/1/ - It works for the most part, but seems to mis-behave a little; though I'm sure that's due to something I've not done correctly.

Answer (score 1):

`getElementByClassName` returns an array-like structure. You should loop through them and bind the event that way.

Comment: It returns a NodeList, which is like an array, but isn't a real array.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, @Daniel - but how do I loop through the above array when it is being set like this: `node: document.getElementsByClassName("qty")`?

Comment: @Quentin how would I loop through the NodeList?

Comment: @JamesKent — `for (var i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++) { ... }`

Comment: @Quentin This may sound dumb, but do I use it like this?: http://jsfiddle.net/7xqeU/

Comment: @JamesKent - you have to call `snack.listener` multiple times.

Comment: I just noticed your answer. Checking it now.